# Problem about reversing the order of integration.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

**Problem:** Find $$\int_1^e\int_0^{\ln x}xy\,dy\,dx$$ with the given order of integration and with the order of integration reversed.

**My Attempt:**
When I solve this problem with the given order of integration, I get $$\frac{e^2-1}{8}$$ and when I solve this problem with the order of integration reversed I get the integral $$\int_0^1\int_0^{e-e^{y}}xy\,dx\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3e^2}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-2e\right).$$
The answers are different and so I must be wrong somewhere. Please point my mistake or provide me with a meaningful hint.

Comment: I get limits of $e^y$ and $e$ on the inner integral.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown In that case, I get the result to be $\frac{3e^2+1}{8}.$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown. Shrey, can you see why?

Comment: No, it gives the same.

Comment: Yes, it gives the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_1^e\int_0^{\ln x}xy\,dy\,dx\\
\int_1^e \frac 12 xy^2 |_0^{\ln x}dx\\
\int_1^e \frac 12 x(\ln x)^2dx\\
\frac 14 x^2\ln^2 x - \frac14 x^2\ln x + \frac 18 x^2 |_1^e\\
\frac 14 e^2 - \frac14 e^2 + \frac 18 e^2 - \frac 18\\
\frac 18 (e^2 - 1)
$

that part looks right

now flipping the order of integration

the region is bounded by:

$y = \ln x\\
y = 0\\
x = e$

$\int_0^1\int_{e^y}^e xy \,dx\, dy\\
\int_0^1\frac 12 y (e^2 - e^{2y})\, dy\\
\frac 14 e^2 y^2 - \frac 18 e^{2y}(2y-1)|_0^1\\
\frac 14e^2 - \frac 18 e^2 - \frac 18\\
\frac 18 (e^2 - 1)
$

Where do you think y0u went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The original integral is $\int_0^e\int_0^{ln(y)} xy dy dx$.  The limits of integration are: x goes from 0 to e and, for every x, y goes from 0 to ln(x).  Drawing a graph of y= ln(x), we see that it goes below the x-axis for x between 0 and 1.  To reverse the order of integration, we need to break the integral into 2 parts, y< 0 and y> 0.  For y< 0, x goes form 0 to $e^y$.  For y> 0, x goes from e^y to e.  The integral is $\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{e^y}^1 xy dxdy+ \int_0^1\int_{e^y}^e xy dxdy$

Comment: I don't know what means "original" in this context. It cannot mean "the one the OP wrote" because he didn't wrote that. I'm confused.

Comment: You are right- the integral with respect to x is from 1 to e, not 0 to e.  Then, of course, what I said about two different integrals does not apply.  In the integral the OP wrote, x goes form 1 to e and, for every e, y goes from 0 to ln(x).  To reverse the order of integration, y must go form 0 to ln(e)= 1 and, for each y, x goes $e^y$ to 1.  The integral is $\int_0^1\int_{e^y}^e xy dxdy$.

Comment: What confused me was the answer accepted :)